# Php echo code for different language on site

Tags: php

I have site (on wordpress) with two languages (pl and en). I use php code to display social media buttons. To this I use "Custom Fields" and the data located in page.
To display social media buttons (pl version) I use this code:

```
<?php
    $social_icons = get_field('social_icons',9);
    if (!empty($social_icons)) {
        echo $social_icons;
    }
?>
```

9 - this is number from the page I have data.
I want to display this in second language (en). The data for this in page number 375.
BTW I use Polylang plugin.
What code I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the language you want to display the side in in a variable.

E.g. `$language`

And then just put another number in the code depending on which language is selected:

```
<?php

if ($language == "en") {
    $page = 375;
} else if ($language == "pl") {
    $page = 9;
} else {
    //any other languages?
}
$social_icons = get_field('social_icons', $page);
if (!empty($social_icons)) {
    echo $social_icons;
}
?>
```